# Items in a CollectionView temporarily "jumbled" when reloadData: called in event handler

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have the following situation:

- I have a CollectionView whose cells each contain a button
- in cellForItemAtIndexPath:, I set a string on each button depending on the cell's [indexPath row]
- in the button's action method, I call reloadData: on the CollectionView (because I need to update the information represented by the button texts)
- momentarily, while the button pressed is selected, the cells in the CollectionView are displayed "jumbled". (Once the button is released, everything returns to "normal" and the cells appear in the correct order: so ultimately, this is an aesthetic issue as far as the application is concerned.)

So specifically, we have code such as this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"MyCellType" forIndexPath: indexPath];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [indexPath row]];
    [cell.answerButton setTitle: str forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // Set tag on button to mark which row no
    // Set button background image depending on some internal data
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)answerButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    // look at button tag, decide which button pressed, update internal
    // data which might mean we need to change button colours
    [_collectionView reloadData];
}
```

I tried putting the call to reloadData: in a dispatch_async to "delay" the update (I come from a Java background, and putting UI updates in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() can sometimes help in cases such as this), but this didn't make a difference.

Can anyone assist: am I doing something wrong, or is this just a UI glitch that I have to live with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of reloading the data for the entire collectionView, try pinpointing just the cell that needs updating.

```
- (IBAction)answerButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    // look at button tag, decide which button pressed, update internal
    // data which might mean we need to change button colours

NSInteger thisTag = button.tag;
NSIndexPath* thisIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:thisTag inSection:0];
[_collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPath:@[thisIndexPath]];

}
```

Comment: Thanks - that does actually solve the problem (even though it makes it seem all the weirder then that reloadData doesn't work properly!).